# <<<_END What exactly does this do?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm a college student trying to do one of the exercises from the book. The exercise is typed below. I typed it in exactly as my textbook said too. What is the purpose of <<_END at the beginning and _END; at the end? When I did it this way my html didn't work correctly. When I did it like the instructor did in his lecture it worked. What he did was put all PHP in separate sections . What is the best way to use PHP, HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3 all in one page? Or should I be linking my HTML page to external JavaScript, CSS3, and PHP pages?
My end goal for this assignment is to build a login page and a create a new account page that is linked to my database.

Any and all tips/help is very much appreciated!!

```
<?php //from the book page 266
echo <<<_END
<html>
<head>
<title>PAGE 266, 267</title>
<body>
<form method="post" action="formtest.php">
What is your name?
<input type="test" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: See the “heredoc” section in the PHP manual on strings • https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: As the previous comment mentions, see [PHP's heredoc info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Also, asking multiple questions in one is done - [ask]